# + operator with images in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am very new to matlab and I am trying to run a program dealing with images. Here is the portion of my code that applies to the problem.

```
function result = shadowremoval(image, type, mask)
  % computing size of the image
  s_im = size(image);

  % creating a shadow segmentation if no mask is available
  if (~exist('mask','var'))
      gray = rgb2gray(image);
      mask = 1-double(im2bw(gray, graythresh(gray)));
  end

  % structuring element for the shadow mask buring, and the shadow/light
  % core detection
  strel = [0 1 1 1 0; 1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1 1; 0 1 1 1 0];

  % computing shadow/light  core (pixels not on the blured adge of the
  % shadow area)
  shadow_core = imerode(mask, strel);
  lit_core = imerode(1-mask, strel);

  % smoothing the mask
  smoothmask = conv2(double(mask), double(strel/21), 'same');

  % averaging pixel intensities in the shadow/lit areas
  shadowavg_red = sum(sum(image(:,:,1).*shadow_core)) / sum(sum(shadow_core));
  litavg_red = sum(sum(image(:,:,1).*lit_core)) / sum(sum(lit_core));

  % additive shadow removal
  % compiting colour difference between the shadow/lit areas
  diff_red = litavg_red - shadowavg_red;

  % adding the difference to the shadow pixels
  result(:,:,1) = image(:,:,1) + smoothmask * diff_red; %this is line 82
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
 Error using  +

 Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

 Error in shadowremoval (line 82)

 result(:,:,1) = image(:,:,1) + smoothmask * diff_red;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't add integers and doubles, unless using a scalar double. For example, `uint8(8) + 9` works, whereas `uint8(8) + [9 10]` doesn't (gives the same error as you get).

Replace the line that gives error to

```
result(:,:,1) = double(image(:,:,1)) + smoothmask * diff_red; %this is line 82
```

that is, cast integers to doubles before doing the addition.

I'm assuming `image` is of integer type and other variables are double. Not really clear from your question.

BTW, it's not a good idea to use `image` as a variable name, because it shadows a Matlab function.